# Помогите исправить ошибку. В строке где написано int* resault_arr = GetPoisitiveNumbers; пишет ошибку нельзя использовать для инициализации типа int*

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void PrintArray(int* dinamic_arr);
int GetPoisitiveNumbers(int* array);

int main()
{
    int* dynamic_var = nullptr;

    int size = 0;
    cin >> size;

    int* dynamic_arr = new int[size] {1, 2};
    int* resault_arr = GetPoisitiveNumbers;
    PrintArray(dynamic_arr);


    return 0;
}

void PrintArray(int* dynamic_arr)
{
    int size = _msize(dynamic_arr) / sizeof(dynamic_arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        dynamic_arr[i] = i + 1;
        cout << *(dynamic_arr + i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int GetPoisitiveNumbers(int* array)
{
    int size = _msize(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    int newSize = 0;
    int* NewArr = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > -1)
            ++newSize;
    }
    NewArr = new int[newSize] {};

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > -1)
        {
            NewArr[j] = array[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }

    return *NewArr;
}
```

Comment: `int* resault_arr = GetPoisitiveNumbers;`

Однако

    `int GetPoisitiveNumbers(int* array);`

Т.е. вы указателю на `int` присваиваете указатель на функцию. Что вы хотите этим добиться?